# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel (Apache Felix Maven Bundle Plugin)

Tags: javafx, osgi, noclassdeffounderror, apache-felix, maven-bundle-plugin

I am trying to use the JFXPanel class with the Apache Felix Maven Bundle Plugin. I´ve tried to export the JavaFX classes into the bundle with the tag  but I always obtain the NoClassDefFoundError exception:

```
    ERROR  10:08:15  Uncaught Exception in thread 'AWT-EventQueue-0'
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel
    at edu.stanford.bmir.protege.examples.view.Metrics.<init>(Metrics.java:42) ~[na:na]
    at edu.stanford.bmir.protege.examples.view.ExampleViewComponent.initialiseOWLView(ExampleViewComponent.java:17) ~[na:na]
    at org.protege.editor.owl.ui.view.AbstractOWLViewComponent.initialise(AbstractOWLViewComponent.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at org.protege.editor.core.ui.view.View.createContent(View.java:413) ~[na:na]
    at org.protege.editor.core.ui.view.View.createUI(View.java:220) ~[na:na]
    at org.protege.editor.core.ui.view.View$1.hierarchyChanged(View.java:124) ~[na:na]
    at java.awt.Component.processHierarchyEvent(Component.java:6700) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6319) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.Component.createHierarchyEvents(Component.java:5549) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.Container.createHierarchyEvents(Container.java:1445) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.Container.createHierarchyEvents(Container.java:1441) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.Container.createHierarchyEvents(Container.java:1441) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.Container.createHierarchyEvents(Container.java:1441) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.Container.createHierarchyEvents(Container.java:1441) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1639) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1671) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1623) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setVisible(JComponent.java:2644) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at javax.swing.JTabbedPane.fireStateChanged(JTabbedPane.java:394) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at javax.swing.JTabbedPane$ModelListener.stateChanged(JTabbedPane.java:270) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at javax.swing.DefaultSingleSelectionModel.fireStateChanged(DefaultSingleSelectionModel.java:132) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at javax.swing.DefaultSingleSelectionModel.setSelectedIndex(DefaultSingleSelectionModel.java:67) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at javax.swing.JTabbedPane.setSelectedIndexImpl(JTabbedPane.java:616) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at javax.swing.JTabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(JTabbedPane.java:591) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI$Handler.mousePressed(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:3647) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:280) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:279) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6530) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4522) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82) [na:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel not found by protege.plugin.examples [30]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1574) ~[org.apache.felix.main.jar:na]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:79) ~[org.apache.felix.main.jar:na]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2018) ~[org.apache.felix.main.jar:na]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    ... 62 common frames omitted
```

This is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>edu.stanford.protege</groupId>
    <artifactId>protege.plugin.examples</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>

    <name>Protege Plugin Examples</name>
    <description>Example plug-ins for the Protege Desktop ontology editor, e.g., views, menu items, etc.</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra>
        javafx.animation,javafx.application,
        javafx.collections,
        javafx.embed.swing,
        javafx.geometry,
        javafx.scene,javafx.scene.layout,
        javafx.scene.transform,
        javax.swing,
        javax.swing.border,
        org.osgi.framework
    </org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.protege</groupId>
            <artifactId>protege-editor-owl</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
                <version>11</version>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <!-- Use resource filtering to replace references to the artifactId in the plugin.xml file -->
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-Activator>org.protege.editor.owl.ProtegeOWL</Bundle-Activator>
                        <Bundle-ClassPath>.</Bundle-ClassPath>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId};singleton:=true</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Vendor>The Protege Development Team</Bundle-Vendor>
                        <Embed-Dependency>javafx</Embed-Dependency>
                        <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
                        <Export-Package>
                            org.protege.editor.owl.*;version="5.0.0", <!-- equivalent to [5.0.0,infinity) -->
                            com.sun.javafx, com.sun.javafx.animation, com.sun.java
                         fx.applet, com.sun.javafx.application, com.sun.javafx.beans, com.sun.
                         javafx.beans.event, com.sun.javafx.binding, com.sun.javafx.charts, co
                         m.sun.javafx.collections, com.sun.javafx.css, com.sun.javafx.css.conv
                         erters, com.sun.javafx.css.parser, com.sun.javafx.cursor, com.sun.jav
                         afx.effect, com.sun.javafx.embed, com.sun.javafx.event, com.sun.javaf
                         x.font, com.sun.javafx.font.coretext, com.sun.javafx.font.directwrite
                         , com.sun.javafx.font.freetype, com.sun.javafx.font.t2k, com.sun.java
                         fx.fxml, com.sun.javafx.fxml.builder, com.sun.javafx.fxml.expression,
                          com.sun.javafx.geom, com.sun.javafx.geom.transform, com.sun.javafx.g
                         eometry, com.sun.javafx.iio, com.sun.javafx.iio.bmp, com.sun.javafx.i
                         io.common, com.sun.javafx.iio.gif, com.sun.javafx.iio.ios, com.sun.ja
                         vafx.iio.jpeg, com.sun.javafx.iio.png, com.sun.javafx.image, com.sun.
                         javafx.image.impl, com.sun.javafx.jmx, com.sun.javafx.logging, com.su
                         n.javafx.media, com.sun.javafx.menu, com.sun.javafx.perf, com.sun.jav
                         afx.print, com.sun.javafx.property, com.sun.javafx.property.adapter, 
                         com.sun.javafx.robot, com.sun.javafx.robot.impl, com.sun.javafx.runti
                         me, com.sun.javafx.runtime.async, com.sun.javafx.runtime.eula, com.su
                         n.javafx.scene, com.sun.javafx.scene.control, com.sun.javafx.scene.co
                         ntrol.behavior, com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin, com.sun.javafx.sce
                         ne.control.skin.caspian, com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.caspian.im
                         ages, com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.modena, com.sun.javafx.scene.
                         control.skin.resources, com.sun.javafx.scene.input, com.sun.javafx.sc
                         ene.layout, com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.region, com.sun.javafx.scene.
                         paint, com.sun.javafx.scene.shape, com.sun.javafx.scene.text, com.sun
                         .javafx.scene.transform, com.sun.javafx.scene.traversal, com.sun.java
                         fx.scene.web, com.sun.javafx.scene.web.behavior, com.sun.javafx.scene
                         .web.skin, com.sun.javafx.sg, com.sun.javafx.sg.prism, com.sun.javafx
                         .sg.prism.web, com.sun.javafx.stage, com.sun.javafx.text, com.sun.jav
                         afx.tk, com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum, com.sun.javafx.util, com.sun.javaf
                         x.webkit, com.sun.javafx.webkit.drt, com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism, com
                         .sun.javafx.webkit.prism.resources, com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.theme
                         , com.sun.javafx.webkit.theme, javafx, javafx.animation, javafx.appli
                         cation, javafx.beans, javafx.beans.binding, javafx.beans.property, ja
                         vafx.beans.property.adapter, javafx.beans.value, javafx.collections, 
                         javafx.collections.transformation, javafx.concurrent, javafx.css, jav
                         afx.embed, javafx.embed.swing, javafx.event, javafx.fxml, javafx.geom
                         etry, javafx.print, javafx.scene, javafx.scene.canvas, javafx.scene.c
                         hart, javafx.scene.control, javafx.scene.control.cell, javafx.scene.e
                         ffect, javafx.scene.image, javafx.scene.input, javafx.scene.layout, j
                         avafx.scene.media, javafx.scene.paint, javafx.scene.shape, javafx.sce
                         ne.text, javafx.scene.transform, javafx.scene.web, javafx.stage, java
                         fx.util, javafx.util.converter,

                        </Export-Package>                
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <pde>true</pde>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

- Java version "1.8.0_241"
- Apache Maven 3.6.3
- OS name: "windows    10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Answer (score 0):

TO DO:
from your pom.xml remove org.openjfx dependecy as it does not contain javafx/embed package. check this [repository](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/tree/develop/modules).

> Use the below dependency to fix the issue

JFXPanel is a component to embed JavaFX content into Swing applications.

In eclipse, right click project --> properties --> Libraries --> Add external jar and choose the jfxrt jar file.

Location of jfxrt.jar in Oracle Java 7:

```
<JRE_HOME>/lib/jfxrt.jar
```

Location of jfxrt.jar in Oracle Java 8:

```
<JRE_HOME>/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar
```

The JRE_HOME will depend on where you have installed the Java.

[image: package available]

[Maven plugin](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin) to run JavaFX 11+ applications.

[Gradle plugin](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-gradle-plugin) to run JavaFX 11+ applications.

I hope this helps.